# Compiling Darknet with opencv-python

Tags: opencv, installation, anaconda, darknet

I installed Darknet with CUDA support. I ran

```
./darknet detector test cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights data/dog.jpg
```

[image]

I want it to run with opencv support. I had already installed opencv.

[image]

I compiled darknet with remake/make after making `OPENCV=1` in Makefile, but still it is not detecting the installed opencv.

How can I make it to detect the already installed opencv?

I have installed opencv with this command `pip install opencv-python --user` before installing darknet.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the c++ libraries not just the python wrapper. You can do it from the sources: https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html.

Answer (score 1):

In order to compile Darknet you will need OpenCV works with C/C++ code, not python. To check whether you have installed OpenCV correctly and can be used in C program, run this command :

```
pkg-config --modversion opencv
```

If it doesn't show anything or shows wrong version, try to reinstall OpenCV **OR** it is possible that your machine doesn't locate opencv version correctly.
 
So add command to your `~/.bashrc` for example :

```
vim ~/.bashrc
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/user/installation/OpenCV-3.4.0/lib/pkgconfig
source ~/.bashrc
```

Notes : Change the path according to your opencv installation directory that contains `opencv.pc`

Answer (score 0):

If you're following this repo https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet for Windows/Linux you need to download openCV (both `OpenCV 2.x.x` and `OpenCV <= 3.4.0` (`3.4.1` and higher isn't supported)) and put in this path for

```
Windows: ( C:\opencv_3.0\opencv\build\include & C:\opencv_3.0\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib)
```

More instructions in the repo. If you're on Windows/Linux and still trying to figure things out you may check a video I made on that topic https://youtu.be/-HtiYHpqnBs

Answer (score 0):

The old AlexeyAB repo has been abandoned for several years now.  The new repo is this one, which has step-by-step instructions on how to install it with OpenCV:  https://github.com/hank-ai/darknet#table-of-contents

In older versions of Darknet, OpenCV was optional.  In the newer versions, OpenCV is required.